# View to double Conversion

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

I need to pass a editTextNumberDecimal to a double in Android Studio, then be able to divide it by another double. How would I go about this? When I try to parse it, it just says that it is still a String.

Comment: Convert the string to a double using Double.parseDouble()

Comment: I appreciate you helping me out. Just fixed my problem!